# After Updating PHP my Apache Stopped working

Tags: php, apache

After installing new php version 5.6.30 i have updated or enabled few functions. After that my apache2.2 stopped working and telling Error 500

also getting the error in restarting httpd:

[image: Error in httpd]

can you suggest me what to do to fix this issue? your kind help is highly appreciated.

Regards
ishtiaque

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You should take a look on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: i know its not a programming but somewhat relevant. sorry for bothering you

Comment: Only trying to help chief :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your screenshot you have to take a look in your `httpd.conf` in line 17.
Looks like you are using `php_admin_value` wrong - maybe in one of your vhosts?

### php_admin_flag

This can only be used within the main Apache configuration and in configuration for vhosts. Use in .htaccess is not allowed. Any php-configuration that type is boolean can be set via `php_admin_flag`.

For example:

```
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
```

If a value is set via `php_admin_flag` you can not overwrite the setting inside your application using `ini_set`.

Comment: Hi, can you check this screen and suggest me what has to be done here: http://prntscr.com/e9fksy

Comment: i have updated my answer. You can not set non-boolean values via `php_admin_flag`